# OSB File Read/Write Proxy Services

Tags: oracle, esb, osb

I'm doing a Proxy Service with Messaging transportation for Any XML and defining the stage, archive and error folders for a xml processing when configuring the proxy service.
I had included an error handler and when reading the file and an error happens, the file must be moved for error folder.
Currently when doing my test and an error happens, the file is moved to archive instead of error folder.
Are there something that I need to add and get this working?
Basically the complete scenario is a Proxy Service polling a folder, reading the XML and sending to Business Services as a XML messaging.
Could you give me directions to make this working or tips that I need to check?

Thanks
Edson

Comment: I found the issue.
The error handler had a reply component and this generated impacts in the error processing.
Now I'm just generate the Log without the reply component.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess - Is it because you have an error handler and you may be doing a success reply from the handler. Have you tested removing the error handler or reply-with-failure from the handler ?